# Open file in eclipse from command line creates new eclipse instance (linux)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I want to open a file in Eclipse from Java. Therefore I use the command line feature like:

```
sh -c <eclipsePath> --launcher.openFile <filePath>
```

Every time the code is executed a new instance of Eclipse opens if I use Linux. If I use the --launcher.openFile command with Windows, the same Eclipse instance is being used. Can anybody tell me what to do to use always the same Eclipse instance to open a file? Thanks! :-)